# AADB2C90068: The provided application with ID is not valid against this service. Please use an application created via the B2C portal and try again.\

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have configured a custom policy that just perform signin (I have removed any other custom step I will use just to make sure the issue is not with policy).

I have followed all instructions for creating IdentityExperienceFramework and ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework. When I run the user flow, it shows the UI screen, posts the request and does not redirect and does not show any errors. Since I enabled application insights, I could see this exception is being thrown.

I am sure I configured the apps as B2C apps and not AD apps, which seems to be a common cause for this issue but this is not the case.

The odd thing is that I have another directory with the same custom policy and with the exactly same configurations and it is working. The only difference is that this directory was created a month ago.

Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: In the error you might have received the App ID, Can you also mention the App ID which is showing there is configured in which line of login-NonInteractive technical profile.

Comment: The App ID that shows on the exception is the same I have on the  <Item Key="client_id"> and <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /> of login-NonInteractive technical profile.

Comment: Is there an error in the browser console? There being no redirect usually means its setup as a Native App, with a redirect URI that a browser cant understand. Use https://jwt.ms as your redirect URL and you might get more clues.

Comment: Actually there is an error in the browser console indicating Internal Server Error. I am already redirecting to jwt.ms.

Comment: Post your policy files.

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question